Does VMMap track deallocations as well as allocations?
I have a native process on Windows which seems to leak memory, i.e. its "private bytes" increases over time.
I thought that the VMMap tool was meant to help with that.
When I use it to run the process, it is able to show the call stack associated with an allocation (as expected):

However:

That first allocation at 0x30D6B008 is said to be 8192 in size
The next allocation is at 0x30D6B030 which is only 0x24 later

So:

How is that possible? To have two allocations so close together, when one is large?
Does is mean that VMMap tracks allocation but does not track/subtract deallocations?
Is there a way to make it show only those allocations which were not since deallocated?

